# C++ Array Constructor Arguments

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor, int, arguments

quick question:

If I have a Class named something(doesn't matter) and then let's say I've something like

```
 int a[2];
 int b[2];

public:

classname(int a[], int b[]); // Constructor
```

In my class (private members) and I want a default constructor (mandatory) to initialize those points (a and b). I'm trying to apply something in my main like:

```
int main(){

classname x({4,5},{1,10});

return 0;
 }
```

But all I get is an error saying that there's no matching constructor. I've also tried with the * instead of [] in the constructor but it doesn't seems to work anyway. I'm just missing something. I'm trying to keep it simple with basic C++.

Thank you.

Comment: sorry, just missed it when posting

Comment: I suggest you look into `std::array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that arrays cannot initialised solely using `{ }`.
They can be initialised when doing this,

```
int arr[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
```

but only because you are "telling" C++ which size the array has. If you try to do this in a constructor it will fail, because it doesn't know which size your array has.
What you want to achieve can be done by using the standard containers. As @NathanOliver suggested, you can use `std::array` but this way you have to specify a fixed size of your array.

```
#include <array>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(std::array<int, 4> a) {};
};

// now you can call it
Test obj1({0, 1, 2, 4});
```

But if you want to make it more flexible and not bound to fix array size, I would suggest using `std::vector` instead.

```
#include <vector>

class Test
{
public:
    Test(std::vector<int> a) {};
};

// now you can call it with as many objects as you want
Test obj1({0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8});
```